# Get decimal separator on Mac

Tags: c++, macos

Can someone explain to me, why I always get `"."` as a decimal separator on my Mac with this simple program, regardless of the system settings?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    std::locale::global(std::locale());
    std::cout << "decimal separator: " << std::use_facet< std::numpunct<char> >(std::cout.getloc()).decimal_point() << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

In the system settings I set the decimal separator to `","`:

[image]

**Note**: When I execute this program on Windows, it returns the correct decimal separator, depending on the system settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The locale you pass in your call to `std::locale::global` uses the default constructor to make a `std::locale` object. That default constructor, in your case, makes a copy of `std::locale::classic`. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale) (bolding mine):

> (1) Default constructor. Constructs a copy of the global C++ locale,
> which is the locale most recently used as the argument to
> std::locale::global **or a copy of std::locale::classic if no call to
> std::locale::global has been made**.

That locale, as its name implies, uses the ['classic' C++ semantics](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/classic), which means using a dot as the decimal separator. I'm not sure why your Windows version behaves differently – when I run your code on my Windows 10 PC, with the system set to use a comma for the decimal separator, I still get a dot reported.

---

In order to report the *actual* current decimal separator, you can use the `locale` constructor with an empty string argument in the call to `global`, then default construct a `std::locale` object and use that to report the current separator:

```cpp
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale{ "" }); // First call sets the environment locale
    std::locale loc; // Default constructor - uses the new locale set in above call
    std::cout << "decimal separator: " << std::use_facet< std::numpunct<char> >(loc).decimal_point() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't actually need to *change* the global locale, just construct the `loc` object using the empty string argument:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::locale loc{ "" };
    std::cout << "decimal separator: " << std::use_facet< std::numpunct<char> >(loc).decimal_point() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

---

And, finally, if you want to set and use the locale in the `std::cout` stream, you need to [`imbue()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue) that stream with the specific locale:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << 1.234 << std::endl; // Uses default (C) separator (dot): 1.234
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale{ "" });
    std::cout << "decimal separator: " << std::use_facet< std::numpunct<char> >(std::cout.getloc()).decimal_point() << "\n";
    std::cout << 1.234 << std::endl; // Uses the system separator (comma): 1,234
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I *think* (but can't *prove*) that changing the global locale doesn't automatically change that used by `std::cout` because that stream has already been constructed **before** you make any calls that change the system/global locale(s).

Comment: What I found out now is the following: 1. On Windows I used the correct constructor (with the `empty string`) and on Mac I used an `empty constructor`, my bad. 2. When running the programm on Mac with XCode I still get a `dot`, even though a `comma` is set in the system settings. Only when running within the console I get the correct separator. 3. The main problem now is, that I need this in a 3rd-party-plugin, but also there I always get the dot as a separator. Any ideas why it behaves like that? Does the local depend on the program it is executed with?

Comment: @Soro One idea: Did you restart Xcode after changing the system settings?

Comment: I just marked your answer as the accepted one, cause it works for my original question. Regardless of that I would like to point out that for the 3rd-party plugin I'm now using some hacky logic to find out if the system-separator is a dot or a comma. (Converting a string "123,456" to double with an SDK-function of the application and checking the result)